# Jquery Clone fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got this jQuery clone plugins which fixes the values of cloned textarea and select (copies the values of cloned elements including textarea and selects).

The code goes like this

```
(function (original) {
    jQuery.fn.clone = function () {
    var result           = original.apply(this, arguments),
        my_textareas     = this.find('textarea').add(this.filter('textarea')),
        result_textareas = result.find('textarea').add(result.filter('textarea')),
        my_selects       = this.find('select').add(this.filter('select')),
        result_selects   = result.find('select').add(result.filter('select'));
        //console.log('this',this)
       //console.log('my',this.find('textarea').length,'rsult',this.filter('textarea'),length);

       for (var i = 0, l = my_textareas.length; i < l; ++i)          
            $(result_textareas[i]).val($(my_textareas[i]).val());
       for (var i = 0, l = my_selects.length;   i < l; ++i) 
            result_selects[i].selectedIndex = my_selects[i].selectedIndex;

       return result;
     };
  }) (jQuery.fn.clone);
```

This is perfect. However these lines

```
my_textareas     = this.find('textarea').add(this.filter('textarea')),
result_textareas = result.find('textarea').add(result.filter('textarea')),
```

What I don't understand is, why would we need to `add`  `.filter('textarea')` again when we have already selected all the textarea inside `this` with `find` (which we loop through to get the value later).

My view is

```
my_textareas     = this.find('textarea'),
result_textareas = result.find('textarea'),
```

Should work just fine without `add(filter..)`.

Is `filter` there for some other reasons?

Comment: My guess is because the textarea can either be part of the collection, or a child of an element in the collection.

Comment: @KevinB..ya you guessed it rite..thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` only gets descendant elements.  `filter` gets only top level elements.

By using both, you get any elements within your collection which are `textarea` as well as those which are descendants of elements which are in your collection.

An example:

```
<div class="abc">
    <textarea id="one"></textarea>
</div>
<textarea class="abc" id="two"></textarea>
```

IF we do this:

```
$(".abc").find("textarea")
```

our collection will contain only the `textarea` with an id of "two".  However, if we do:

```
$(".abc").filter("textarea")
```

our collection will contain only the `textarea` with an id of "one".  The code as you posted uses both which would get both "one" and "two".

Comment: ok so that means .. if i am using clone for textarea itself(as a collection)  the `.filter()` here will get that textarea..where as if the textarea is inside a container which i cloned..then `.find()` comes into play.. yup... that is it..

Comment: and yes in my case .. just find was working since my collection was a `<div>` and textarea was inside it... perfect this makes sense now.. thanks a lot.. :)